# "File is not writable" error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I try to edit any file, I just get this tiny pop up with the message "File is not writable". Any idea on what could be the cause for this?

[image]

#### Update:

- I just deleted the project from my local
- Took a fresh checkout
- Opened it again on Android Studio; and it worked

Note: Still don't know what went wrong though, and would still like to know what happened.

Comment: Please take the good habit of posting your code and errors as **text**, not as images.

Comment: there is no code involved here, just a tiny pop up...

Comment: The popup is hovering on your existing code. Or there would be no issue at all.

Comment: When I try to type something in (edit) the file, Android Studio seems to prevent me from doing so; Is there any (Android Studio) configuration that would help me prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Then it's possible that your folder (or just some specific files) is read-only (maybe it comes from another computer). In Windows it's easy to remove the read-only protection, I have no clue on how to do that on an Apple machine.

Comment: Doesn't the scope say drive.readonly on it?

Comment: <s>Where are you seeing the scope?</s> You meant the scope in the code? There is no issue with the code; My question is about Android Studio making my code readonly...

Answer (score 1):

You download your Android Source Code through ROOT user . So you must run Android Studio with ROOT user . You can also download your Android Source Code through NOT ROOT user !